# Custom UINavigationBar button not displaying

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uinavigationbar

(edited: added more information at bottom)

Firstly I have looked through similar posts and tried their answers but with no luck :( I have a custom navigation bar (just a custom background image) and I'm trying to add a custom back button.

```
// custom back button.
UIButton *backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *backImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back.png"];
backBtn.titleLabel.text = @"";
[backBtn setBackgroundImage:backImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(backPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 54, 33);

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtn];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = @"";
```

The above code is meant to add the button but it does not display on the nav bar. I can still click the area where its meant to appear and it does bring me back to the previous view?! removing the above code displays the standard back button.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

(edit)

Hi again guys,

I tried all your suggestions and still no luck :( I probably should have mentioned earlier that I have a custom nav bar image using the following code. This might be affecting the display of my custom back button image.

This code displays a custom image depending upon a parameter I set. Thanks again for further help!

```
// custom navigation bar image
@implementation UINavigationController (CustomImage)

// set the background image for the nav bar.
- (void) setCustomNavBar:(NSInteger)screen {

UIImage *navBarImg;
switch (screen) {
    case kCreateHuntScreenIdentifier:
        navBarImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"title_create-hunt.png"];
        break;

    case kCreateLocationsScreenIdentifier:
        navBarImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"title_create-location.png"];
        break;

    case kListNewLocationsScreenIdentifier:
        navBarImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"title_choose-location.png"];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:navBarImg];
[[[self.navigationBar subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
[self.navigationBar addSubview:imgView];
[imgView release];
}

@end
```

Comment: OK if I dont display a custom image for the navigation bar the custom back button does display! will try to see if I get both to display together and I will post an update here if I figure out whats happening!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks again for all your advice! I finally found a solution :D

Very quickly I needed to be able to change the background image for a navigation bar from view to view when I pushed or popped the stack.

Using the most popular methods such as overriding the UINavigationBar's drawRect would only partly work, it would work on the root view but then push the image to the front of the navigation bar's stack for every other screen no matter if I sent it to the back, etc.

I found the solution here: http://sebastiancelis.com/2009/12/21/adding-background-image-uinavigationbar/

Take a read, it works great :)

Comment: Just an update as this post is well over a year old, with the introduction of iOS5 Apple recommends you subclass UINavigationBar for custom backgrounds.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm working on an App where I need support for iOS 5 and iOS 4.3,this was exactly what I was looking for. For iOS5 I'm using this 
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:navBarBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Answer (score 1):

```
UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgname.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(method_name:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btn.frame=CGRectMake(3, 2, 53, 30);
UIBarButtonItem *btnBack=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=btnBack;
[btnBack release];
[btn release];
```

Comment: use this in viewDidLoad method

Comment: Yup thats the correct answer you need to define UIBarButtonItem  and alloc them first.Moreover you can take a view as well for some custom implementation,and then add buttons subview to View.Then alloc UIBarButton item with the custom view that you designed....and follow the above answered process for further

Comment: Thanks dks1725 and sabby but I'm afraid that did not work for me :( I'm guessing it must be something to do with the way I set the custom navigation bar background image so I included my code in an edit. note that if I leave out the custom button image the default one appears as normal :/

Comment: Why do you use [btn release]; ? It's abundant.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

befor writing the code for .leftBarButtonItem .Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Swastik but no luck with that either :(